# 3-dimensional 2nd order ODE, for plotting orbit (integrating gravity equation) on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, gravity, orbit

I'd like to ask a question about a problem that has been bothering me for a few days.

I want to integrate a very simple gravitational equation to find the X, Y, Z (position) of an object. It's similar to solving a second-order ODE with three axes X, Y, and Z.

The desired result is to have an orbit that repeats like a spring (as shown in the picture). However, the result from my Matlab code is more like a projectile trajectory.

I think all the lines are appropriate. Therefore, I'm confused as to why the accurate solution is not emerging. Is there any issue that I might be overlooking?

I would appreciate it if you could point out the issues in my code. The code I have written can be seen below.

[Gravity Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EstR.png)

[correct graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHWox.png)

[my wrong graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wpUv.png)

```
clc; clear;

%% parameters
G = 6.67430e-11;  % J*m/kg^2 Gravitational constant
M = 5.9722e24; % kg, Earth Mass

%% Initial conditions
% x0 y0 z0 xdot0 ydot0 zdot0
initial_state = [6.0827e6; 3.4907e6; 4.6517e6; -651.3041; 1082.1; 7426.4];  % Example initial state

%% time
n = 0.001078; % rad/s
p = 2*pi/n; % period
tspan = [0 p];  % Time span for the simulation

%% Solve
[t, result] = ode45(@(t, y) unconstranined_ECI_ode(t, y, G, M), tspan, initial_state);

% ECI X Y Z
X = result(:, 1);
Y = result(:, 2);
Z = result(:, 3);
ECImatrix = [X Y Z];

%% Plot
figure;

subplot(1, 2, 1);
plot(X, Z);
title('Unconstrained Motion in the xz-plane');
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Z');
grid on;

subplot(1, 2, 2)
plot(Y, Z);
title('Unconstrained Motion in the yz-plane');
xlabel('Y');
ylabel('Z');
grid on;

%% ODE solve function
function state = unconstranined_ECI_ode(t, y, G, M)

    vel = y(4:6); % X dot
    r = y(1:3); % X
    rnorm = norm(r);
    rhat = r/rnorm;
    accel = -(G*M/rnorm^2)*rhat;
    state = [vel;accel];
    
end
```

Comment: It is unbound because the gravitational forces acting on the Earth are due to the much larger mass of sun. Swap Earth Mass value for Solar Mass value and you might get something a lot more realistic. Conserving energy in these simulations is distinctly non-trivial.  Doing it all in the x-y orbital plane makes life easier too.

Comment: @MartinBrown Thank you for your advice. I need the position of a satellite relative to Earth. Initially, I was making a mistake; I should triple the period. It should be tspan = [0 pi*3]. However, I have encountered another issue. The orbit should repeat three times, but in my case, it only repeats twice. I'm having trouble figuring out where I went wrong.

Comment: ![secondgraph](https://mail.naver.com/read/image/original/?mimeSN=1708197837.943469.27347.59136&offset=22792&size=140518&u=teachthegrace28&cid=5ec455de2288e361594cef19cc12f92@cweb014.nm.nfra.io&contentType=image/png&filename=1708197834005.png&org=1)

Comment: Using your state vector, I get n = 5.8727e-04, which is much smaller than the n you have in your code. This makes the period much larger than you calculate.  You might double check your numbers.

Comment: @JamesTursa yes, it's just problem of some initial  values. Thank you for your help!